# Update all local copies with git

Tags: git

I have two local copies of a repository, say `a` and `b`, and both local copies have cloned from a remote `origin`. How can I automatically pull changes from the `master` branch on `b` when `a` does a commit and push in this branch?

Note: `b` will **only** be on the `master` branch at all times, and should only update when `origin/master` has been pushed/merged or updated in any way.

Comment: Do you just need `b`'s `master` branch to stay in sync with `origin/master`? Does it have to be due to pushes into `origin` from `a`?

Comment: Yes, I just need `b`'s working copy to stay in sync with what is at `origin/master`. It doesn't matter that it came from `a`, just that it matches what's in `origin`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

You would create a pre-push hook on repo `a`, that triggers the git commands that update `b`. There would be no need to pull from `origin`. `b` could simply pull from `a`.

And note that you can use local filesystem paths with git operations. as in:

```
git push /path/to/b origin/master
```

Comment: Does this still work if I were to have a `c` working copy and if there are commits and pushes from this one to `origin`? Potentially there could be lots of local copies, but `b` would always need to stay in sync with what's currently at `origin/master`.

Comment: Yes. It would work. If `c` is about to push to `origin` `master`, and that push is going to be successful, the hook would pull in the correct data to `b`. If, on the other hand, `a` tried to push, but `c` got there first, and `a` was told it had to pull first, your "'pre-push" hook should stay quiet

Comment: actually. the [post-merge](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/githooks.txt#L167) hook might be more useful for you. "This hook ... is not executed, if the merge failed due to conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

push local master branch to remote b's master branch

```
git push b master:master
```

fetch and merge remote b's master branch with current local branch

```
git pull b/master
```

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation? This popped up in the review queue.

Comment: Please see the new answer